# Trying to import from Github to Bitbucket and receiving an "Select a valid choice. source-git is not one of the available choices."

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

The title says it all. I have a moderate knowledge of git, enough for my daily personal projects, as a solo dev.

I read on Bitbucket docs that I have to create a token with some options enabled but even that didn't work. It shows that my user is authenticated but after I try to import, it shows that it isn't anymore.

So, do you know how can I import from Github to Bitbucket properly, using the Bitbucket Import feature?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue today.  I've imported at least a dozen other repositories from Github to a private Bitbucket Cloud account over the past year, but it's failing today (3 Feb 2020) with that same error.